How does the mechanism for this intermediate even occur? How does the amine replace the vinyl ether?
This is a "Friedlander−Pfitzinger" reaction, turning the Isatin to a Quinidine. For the Amine to replace the Vinyl Ether on (17), that Vinyl Ether would need to be Hydrolyzed. That, however, only happens in strong acids, while this is basic. By what mechanism does the amine replace the vinyl ether here if the conditions are basic?
Paper Source: http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jacs.6b04339



The opening of isatin is correct but the nitrogen is protonated. The nitrogen adds to enone 17 with elimination of methoxide. Intermediate 19 is like an enamine that adds to the ketone followed by elimination. Welcome to ChemSE.

Allow me to expand on my brief description in the Comments on how 19 and 16 are formed. You correctly realized that the first step was saponification of isatin 18. Your product of saponification in solution should have the negatively charged nitrogen protonated and the carboxylic acid and phenolic groups deprotonated. After acidic workup, both of these groups are protonated.
Primary amine 1 will add to α,β-unsaturated ketone 17 in a conjugate fashion to form intermediate 2. While this step may be reversible, eventually the nitrogen is deprotonated (red arrow) and methoxide is eliminated (blue arrows) to form enone 3 wherein your aromatic residue is designated by the R-group. This process is like the ammonolysis of an ester to an amide but in a vinylogous fashion. After all, 17 is a vinylogous ester and 3 is a vinylogous amide.
Compound 19 in aqueous NaOH will not only have the carboxyl and phenolic groups deprotonated but also the nitrogen. This is likely because the nitrogen is part of a vinylogous amide. [Think about the first step in the Hofmann rearrangement]. In transition state 4, the nitrogen donates a pair of electrons to the adjacent carbon to allow 1,2-addition to the carbonyl group which, in turn, is protonated to form 5. The designated C-H bond has overlap with the π-electrons of the imine function but also with the carbonyl group, which  has free rotation about the red bond. This C-H bond is readily deprotonated followed by the elimination of hydroxide and, after acidification, the quinoline 16.

